# jquery go to top

Tags: jquery

when i click the next button it is suposed to go to the top of the next page but it only scrolls 3/4 of the way up...anyone have any sugestions?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $("a#checkout-next").click( function() {
            $("#shopping-cart-form").fadeIn();
            var checkoutWidth = $("#shopping-cart").width() + 30;
            $("#checkout-bar-in").animate( {
                width :'+=50%'
            });
            $("#checkout-slider").animate( {
                marginLeft :'-=' + checkoutWidth
            }, 800, function() {
                $('body,html').animate( {
                    scrollTop :0
                }, 800);
            });
            return false;
        });
        $("a#checkout-back").click( function() {
            $("#shopping-cart-form").fadeOut();
            var checkoutWidth = $("#shopping-cart").width() + 30;
            $("#checkout-bar-in").animate( {
                width :'-=50%'
            });
            $("#checkout-slider").animate( {
                marginLeft :'+=' + checkoutWidth
            }, 800, function() {
                $('body,html').animate( {
                    scrollTop :0
                }, 800);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$(window).animate(.....);
```

Comment: in stead of  `$('body,html').animate( {scrollTop :0}, 800);`  Do you think i should still use `{scrollTop :0}, 800` ?